# Failover proxy on Amazon aws?

Tags: proxy, amazon-web-services, failover

This is a fairly generic question. Suppose I have three ec2 boxes: two app boxes and a box that hosts nginx as a reverse proxy, delegating requests to the two app boxes (my database is hosted elsewhere). Now, the two app machines can absorb a failure amongst themselves, however the third one represents a single point of failure. How can I configure my setup so that if the reverse proxy goes down, the site is still available?

I am looking at keepalived and HAproxy. For me this stuff is non-obvious, and any help for the ears of a beginner is appreciated.

Comment: A perhaps related question is, can I have several EC2 instances behind one elastic IP address? This way, I can put two machines with reverse proxies there, and if one fails, another carries on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your nginx does no much more than proxying HTTP requests, please have a look at Amazon Elastic Load Balancer. You can set up your two (or more) app boxes, leave some spare ones (in order to keep always two or more up, if you need it), set up health checks, have SSL termination at the balancer, make use of sticky sessions, etc.

There is a lot of people, though, that would like to see the ability to set elastic IP addresses to ELBs, and others with good arguments why it is not neeeded.

My suggestions is that you take a look at [ELB documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), as it seems to perfectly fit your needs. I also recommend reading this [interesting post](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/elastic-in-elastic-load-balancing-elb.html) for a good discussion on this subject.

Comment: I was also suggested to look at Nagios and Heartbeat. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. My team have investigated Nagios and it is great. But for monitoring, and not for failover. You should probably combine redundancy (by adding more than one node to a load balancer and/or cluster) **and also** using a monitoring tool like Nagios.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are a beginner with HA and clusters, your best solution is Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) which is maintained by Amazon. They scale up automatically and implements a high availability cluster of balancers. So using ELB service you already mitigate the point of failure that you commented. Also it's important to have in mind that an ELB is cheaper than 2 instances in AWS. And of course it's easier to launch and maintain.

You can't see multiple ELB because it is a service, so you don't have to take care of the availability.

Other important point is that AWS elastic ips aren't assigned to NIC interface of your OS instance, so use virtual ips as well in classical infrastructures it's difficult.

After this explanation, if you still want Nginx as a proxy reverse in AWS because your reasons, I think you can implement an autoscaling group with a layer composed by Nginx instances. But if you aren't expert in autoscaling technology, it could be very tricky.